# Add new variable to magento core config

Tags: magento

What is the best way to add a new config setting in the configuration->Catalog->Search Engine Optimisations or any other such location in the core configuration.

I am developing an extension which will need to use this setting that I will define here.

Thanks
karam

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing an extension, you can configure your field for administration using `system.xml`. The xpath  will be `catalog/groups/seo/fields/your_field` (ref. `Mage/Catalog/etc/system.xml`).

To set a default for this value, you can either add the value to your module's config.xml using the xpath `default/catalog/seo/your_field`, or you can create an install script which will write the value to `core_config_data`.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that shud work.I ll update here after trying.Thanks for the quick response.